# Graphael pie.js unhover event missing

Tags: svg, raphael, pie-chart, graphael

Graphael doesn't have an unhover event for some odd reason. Found this chunk of code in pie.js that creates hover events:

```
chart.hover = function (fin, fout) {
    fout = fout || function () {};

    var that = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        (function (sector, cover, j) {
            var o = {
                sector: sector,
                cover: cover,
                cx: cx,
                cy: cy,
                mx: sector.middle.x,
                my: sector.middle.y,
                mangle: sector.mangle,
                r: r,
                value: values[j],
                total: total,
                label: that.labels && that.labels[j]
            };
            cover.mouseover(function () {
                fin.call(o);
            }).mouseout(function () {
                fout.call(o);
            });
        })(series[i], covers[i], i);
    }
    return this;
};
```

The unhover event is Raphael JS is the following code snippet. Using these two there must be a way to create an unhover for a Grapael pie chart. Any help here will be very very greatly appreciated as I'm stumped!

```
elproto.unhover = function (f_in, f_out) {
    return this.unmouseover(f_in).unmouseout(f_out);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hover event takes two functions - f_in and f_out

so (using the example i'm working on right now)

```
pie.hover(
    // hover function
    function () {
        this.sector.stop();
        this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);
    },
    // un-hover function 
    function () {
        this.sector.scale(0.9, 0.9, this.cx, this.cy);
    }
);
```

Comment: Gotta try this tomorrow when I bust out the code. Will let you know how it goes.